# iOS Swift How to Jump in middle of an animation

Tags: swift, animation, seek

Say, the animate timeDuration is 10 seconds. But, would like to start animation from between say from 5th second. In Android there is valueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(int). 
Please guide the Swift equivalent for the same.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an equivalent with system libraries.  The closest thing I can think of, would be to start the animation and mid-way you interrupt the animation to start another one using .beginFromCurrentState.  Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do it using an `UIViewPropertyAnimator`

You will need to create the animation inside the initialiser, where you set the duration in seconds and the timing curve.

```
var animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .linear, animations: {

   //animating the change of position for an object
    objectToAnimate.frame = objectToAnimate.frame.offsetBy(dx: 100, dy: 0)
})
animator.pauseAnimation()
```

If you want a more complex animation with Bézier or spring-based timing use the other inits.

Based on the users interaction you can ***start***, ***continue*** or ***pause*** animation. After creating the animator object you should ***pause*** your animation so it doesn't go off right after you create it.

```
animator.pauseAnimation()

animator.startAnimation()

animator.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0)
```

And you can also set the percentage of your animation in order to start from a certain point of your animation.

```
animator.fractionComplete = 0.5
```

> jumping to the middle of the animation, 50% of it already being done

I strongly recommend going through the [WWDC Animation Keynote](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/) if you want to get a very good understanding of how it works.